# How to make a 3D element with an extrude effect?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I created an isometric 10x10 field with:

```css
transform : rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg)
```

[image: teste]

Is there any property that modifies divs "z-heigth", allowing me to give each of the inner cells a different "depth", creating a column?

Cell and Table current code:

```css
#table {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg)
}

#table>DIV {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cells are created via JS. I don't believe html is necessary here, I just need the CSS property that controls 3-dimension size

Comment: Your HTML allows us to more quickly reproduce your problem, see and explain mistakes made in your code, and better help us provide applicable solutions. It's also a requirement of the site that you post your "*[mcve]*" code (which, in this case, includes the HTML). Without that [mcve] code your question is eligible for closure as off-topic.

Comment: Note to get a true isometric projection with 30° angles you need `rotateX(54.736deg)` which is atan(sqrt(2)). To get your isometric to scale you also need to append `scale3D(1.2247,  1.2247,  1.2247)` which is sqrt(3)/sqrt(2). Demo can be found [here](https://codepen.io/scootman/pen/QWvYoyY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some perspective and transform. Don't forget to add `transform-style:preserve-3d;` to the parent element

```css
#table {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* this is important */
}

#table > * {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div:nth-child(50) {
  transform:perspective(100px) translateZ(30px);
}
/* or without perspective */
div:nth-child(10) {
  transform:translateZ(30px);
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Also like below by adding pseudo element to create 'walls'

```css
#table {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* this is important */
}

#table > * {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div:nth-child(7n + 3) {
  transform:translateZ(58px);
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* this is important */
}
div:nth-child(7n + 3)::before,
div:nth-child(7n + 3)::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:inherit;
  border:inherit;
}
div:nth-child(7n + 3)::before {
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:rotateY(90deg);
}
div:nth-child(7n + 3)::after {
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform:rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

To make it generic we can add some CSS variables:

```css
#table {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* this is important */
}

#table > * {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div[style*='--d'] {
  transform:translateZ(var(--d));
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* this is important */
}
div[style*='--d']::before,
div[style*='--d']::after{
  content:"";
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  background:inherit;
  border:inherit;
}
div[style*='--d']::before {
  width:var(--d);
  top:0;
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:rotateY(90deg);
}
div[style*='--d']::after {
  height:var(--d);
  right:0;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform:rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div style="--d:150px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div style="--d:70px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div style="--d:20px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div style="--d:40px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div  style="--d:100px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

[image: CSS 3D columns]

Some animation for the fun:

```css
#table {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* this is important */
}

#table > * {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div[style*='--d'] {
  transform:translateZ(var(--d));
  animation:a 2s linear infinite alternate;
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* this is important */
}
div[style*='--d']::before,
div[style*='--d']::after{
  content:"";
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  background:inherit;
  border:inherit;
  animation:inherit;
}
div[style*='--d']::before {
  width:var(--d);
  top:0;
  animation-name:c;
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:rotateY(90deg);
}
div[style*='--d']::after {
  height:var(--d);
  right:0;
  animation-name:b;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  transform:rotateX(90deg);
}

@keyframes a {
  from {
    transform:translateZ(0);
  }
}
@keyframes b {
  from {
    height:0px;
  }
}
@keyframes c {
  from {
    width:0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div style="--d:150px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div style="--d:70px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div style="--d:20px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div style="--d:40px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div  style="--d:100px;"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the impression (though I may well be wrong) that the OP wants to extrude that plane from the base layer to form a 3D 'column' rather than simply translating the plane upwards. Though the question is ambiguous on that point.

Comment: That's really awesome! Yes David, i was not clear, I'm sorry. I intended to create a column. But Temani's solution's also pretty nice

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica how a 3D 'column'? you comment is also ambiguous to me :) I am not getting the shape in my mind

Comment: @abcson can you share the result of the column you want? a screenshot maybe

Comment: Think of a 3d extrusion, so that the elevated element that's currently floating off the base layer has 'sides' that extend from that base layer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif By column we mean a Solid Block. Your solution creates the column 'ceil', the 'walls' are missing

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica ok, now we have the columns ;)

Comment: You nailed it. Tank you very much!

Comment: I tougth css would have an '3d dimension size', but that seems very costly. Creating just the outside walls is certainly better